# Render a partial view with single model from a partial view using an IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to figure out how to render a single model from a view that is using an IEnumerable of that model.  I can't seem to figure out how to send it using the razor

Right now I am getting the error:

```
MyApp.Models.DefectsVM' is a 'type' but is being used like a 'variable'
```

On this line in my main view(Under DefectsVM model I am trying to pass in):

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Defect/defectsPartial.cshtml", DefectsVM);}
```

My partial view has this in it to use a model:

```
@model MyApp.Models.DefectsVM
```

And my main view is using this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.DefectsVM>
```

I am not sure what all other information is needed, let me know if I need to edit.  But thank you for reading and taking your time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to your model with `Model`. But in your case, `Model` will return an `IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.DefectsVM>`, so you will need to iterate over that, and then render your partial.

Something like:

```
foreach(var defectsVM in Model)
{
    @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Defect/defectsPartial.cshtml", defectsVM);}
}
```

Regardless of whether the `IEnumerable` contains one or more than one, it should work.